# Is every projective $\mathbf{Z}[x]$-module free?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, projective-modules

Is every finitely generated projective $\mathbf{Z}[x]$-module free?

Comment: Quillen-Suslin theorem http://amathew.wordpress.com/2012/01/16/the-quillen-suslin-theorem/

Comment: "If k is a principal ideal domain then any projective module over k[x1,...,xn] is free."  Thanks Fernando!

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: And again the comment box is misused for answers.

Comment: I do not understand the votes to close.  The Quillen-Suslin theorem is well-known to experts, but I am sure there are a great many research mathematicians who are unfamiliar with it.  

Comment: @Steven: I guess that in some people's education, "subobject of free is free" results get introduced or alluded to.

Comment: (Yes, I know that the slogan I put in quotes is usually not true, and that projectives are retracts of free, not sub objects, before anyone jumps on)

Comment: @Martin, even though I personally thought the question deserved an answer, it's possible to want to give a quick answer in a comment while still harboring a feeling that the question might not be quite appropriate for MO, on the grounds that the answer is eminently searchable through Google and therefore simple. I can appreciate that someone might feel shy about being awarded points for answering 'cheaply' a borderline-appropriate question. By the way, quid added to a meta thread: http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1537/an-elementary-question-thoughts/#Item_16 

Answer (score 29, accepted):

While it's certainly true (per Fernando's comment) that this is a special case of the Quillen-Suslin theorem, it was certainly known long before Quillen and Suslin came along.

There's a paper of Murthy from the mid-1960s which shows that every projective $R[x]$-module is extended whenever $R$ is a regular ring of dimension at most 2.  ("Extended" here means "of the form $P[x]$ where $P$ is a projective $R$-module".  Since all projective ${\mathbb Z}$-modules are free, extended is equivalent to free in this case.)

But there's an even earlier paper of Bass which covers the case where $R$ is regular of dimension 1, which is all you need.    The paper is called "Torsion Free and Projective Modules".

**Edited to add:**  And the case of a PID predates even Bass; I think it's due to Seshadri in the 1950s.

Comment: Glad this informative answer got posted before the question gets closed...

Comment: This is a great answer. I was pretty sure when Fernando gave his answer in the comments he was nuking flies and that this special case must be much easier. Also I should add that I am pretty sure Serre's original conjecture was over a field and many people might not realize Quillen-Suslin works over PIDs. 

Comment: I'm sure Serre didn't make any conjecture at all on this topic.

Comment: Well it was known as the Serre conjecture although he himself apparently never owned the name. 

http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quillen–Suslin_theorem

Comment: Hmm the link didn't copy correctly. http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quillen-Suslin_theorem

Comment: Steve Thanks for this, and for convincing me not to recycle!

Comment: @Fernando: It's entirely possible that Serre didn't ask whether projective modules over polynomial rings were free in precisely those words (and it seems to be true that he strenuously objected to the term "Serre's conjecture"). However, according to Lang's Algebra (3rd edition), page 846, Serre did ask about the very closely related unimodular extension property over polynomial rings. 

Comment: Todd:  Serre surely knew that the unimodular extension property is equivalent to Quillen/Suslin (this is basically a restatement of Serre's computation of $K_0$).  I think the issue Fernando has in mind is not whether Serre was interested in this question but whether he expected a particular answer.

Comment: @Todd Trimble. For what I know, Serre sees an enormous difference in stating a conjecture and asking a question, even when he suggests what the answer to the question should be.

Comment: Steve, ACL: of course you both are correct. (Steve, my wording should suggest that *of course* Serre knew the equivalence!) Anyway, sorry for the noise. 

Answer (score 13):

When $R$ is a PID, then every finitely generated projective $R[x]$-module is free. As Steven already said, this is due to Seshadri. Here is the reference:

> Seshadri, C.S., [Triviality of vector bundles over the affine space $K^2$](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC335443/pdf/pnas00684-0093.pdf), Proc. Nat. Acad. Sci. USA **44** (1958), 456-458.